# Ошибка при получении имени файлов из директории

Tags: java, netbeans

Здравствуйте. Вот код для получения массива имени файлов из директории:

```
public class Main 
{
static int c = 1;
static String loginuser;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    loginuser = "admin";

    String folderName = "admin";
    File folder = new File("/home/torin/NetBeansProjects/CMS/"
            + folderName + "/");
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();

    String[] namefiles = null;

    boolean bool = folder.exists();

    if(bool)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
        {
            namefiles[i] = files[i].getName();
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(files[i]);
    }

    /*String[] namefiles = null;
    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        namefiles[i] = files[i].getName();
    }*/

    /*try
    {
        String template = "Main";
        String folderName = "admin";
        File folder = new File("/home/torin/NetBeansProjects/mavenproject1/" + folderName);

        if (!folder.exists()) 
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File[] s = folder.listFiles();
        if(s.length > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) 
            {
                c++;
            }
        }

        String fileName = folder + "/" + "index" + c + ".jsp";
        //String fileName = "index.jsp";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");

        if(template.equals("Main и footer"))
        {
            writer.println("<%@page contentType=\"text/html\" "
                    + "pageEncoding=\"UTF-8\"%>");
            writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            writer.println("<html>");
            writer.println("\t<head>");
            writer.println("\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
            writer.println("\t\t<title>Тест</title>");
            writer.println("\t</head>\n");
            writer.println("\t<body>");
            writer.println("\t\t<main>");
            writer.println("\t\t</main>");
            writer.println("\t</body>");
            writer.println("</html>");
        }
        else if(template.equals("Main и footer"))
        {
            writer.println("<%@page contentType=\"text/html\" "
                    + "pageEncoding=\"UTF-8\"%>");
            writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            writer.println("<html>");
            writer.println("\t<head>");
            writer.println("\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
            writer.println("\t\t<title>Тест</title>");
            writer.println("\t</head>\n");
            writer.println("\t<body>");
            writer.println("\t\t<main>");
            writer.println("\t\t</main>");
            writer.println("\t\t<footer>");
            writer.println("\t\t</footer>");
            writer.println("\t</body>");
            writer.println("</html>");
        }
        else if(template.equals("Header и main"))
        {
            writer.println("<%@page contentType=\"text/html\" "
                    + "pageEncoding=\"UTF-8\"%>");
            writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            writer.println("<html>");
            writer.println("\t<head>");
            writer.println("\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
            writer.println("\t\t<title>Тест</title>");
            writer.println("\t</head>\n");
            writer.println("\t<body>");
            writer.println("\t\t<header>");
            writer.println("\t\t</header>");
            writer.println("\t\t<main>");
            writer.println("\t\t</main>");
            writer.println("\t</body>");
            writer.println("</html>");
        }
        else if(template.equals("Header, main и footer"))
        {
            writer.println("<%@page contentType=\"text/html\" "
                    + "pageEncoding=\"UTF-8\"%>");
            writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            writer.println("<html>");
            writer.println("\t<head>");
            writer.println("\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
            writer.println("\t\t<title>Тест</title>");
            writer.println("\t</head>\n");
            writer.println("\t<body>");
            writer.println("\t\t<header>");
            writer.println("\t\t</header>");
            writer.println("\t\t<main>");
            writer.println("\t\t</main>");
            writer.println("\t\t<footer>");
            writer.println("\t\t</footer>");
            writer.println("\t</body>");
            writer.println("</html>");
        }
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/


}
}
```

Ошибка после запуска проекта

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mavenproject1: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: У вас ошибка при сборке, причем тут получение файлов...

Comment: А в чем именно ошибка?

Comment: @Zhuk maven же вам пишет "Чтобы увидеть полный текст ошибки, запустите Maven с ключом -e"

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо